# How to check if a pending transaction nonce has duplicate?

Tags: web3js, etherscan

Is there a web3 function or other workaround to check if the pending tx has duplicate nonce?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normal Ethereum node mempool stores every transaction only once.

You would need to run modified Ethereum nodes in peer-to-peer network to get this information.

Comment: I think he's trying to avoid the `"nonce too low"` and/or `"replacement transaction underpriced"` transaction errors. The simple solution to that is usually to just re-transmit the transaction.

Comment: I wanted to check if the current pending transaction has other duplicate nonce from othe tx sender just like how etherscan shows a warning on the first tx nonce

Comment: You need a special node for that - you cannot do it with out of the box open source software as far as I know

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa Calling get`web3.eth.getTransactionCount("pending")` it is possible to obtain the latest nonce also considering transactions in the pending pool. Since it only check the local node pool it might not work in some cases.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't mess with the internals of your client, e.g. Geth, for obvious security and reliability reasons, but you can leverage a decent wallet middleware and modify it to keep track of overlapping transactions with same nonce in the mempool. Metamask provides a good library *web3-provider-engine/subproviders/nonce-tracker.js*. You can modify to hold an object that contains multiple txns on same nonce for pending transactions. Let me know if you're interested.